# how I place this.state inside ""?

Tags: reactjs, state

here, I want access to 'this.state.select1' & 'this.state.select2' as factor's object attributes, in the handleClick event handler. how I place these in "", in the way that not become string? because output give me NaN.

This is the desired part of my code:

```
const factor = {
    kilometer: 1,
    meter: 1000,
    centimeter: 100000,
    millimeter: 1000000
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: '',
            select1: '',
            select2: '',
            result: 0
        }
    }
    handleChange1 = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            text: e.target.value
            }
        );
    }
    handleChange2 = (e) => {
        this.setState({
                select1: e.target.value
            }
        );
    }
    handleChange3 = (e) => {
        this.setState({
                select2: e.target.value
            }
        );
    }
    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            result: (parseInt(this.state.text) * factor['this.state.select1']) /
                factor['this.state.select2']
        });
    }
```

output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUPGE.png)

Comment: You don't want `factor['this.state.select1']`, you want `factor[this.state.select1]` (notice the lack of quotes)

Comment: @AGE this worked. thanks a lot

Comment: @Ben thanks a lot. but **factor[this.state.select1]** give me NaN in output. **factor[`${this.state.select1}`]** this worked. behind "$" and after "}" have " ` ". this don't show.

Comment: I suspect it's because it's case sensitive, your `factor` object has everything in all lowercase, but in your screenshot it has the first letter capitalized. You can use `toLowerCase` so it works.

Comment: @Ben of course value's attrubutes existing in the option tag inside select tag is lowercase. and I thing, this is that must be match with factor's names. right is?